# Formatter in VsCode for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formatter

When I save or format my React code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> the code below, is formatted in a strange way.

How can I solve this?

Default code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Hello CodeCademy
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After formatting the code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return ( <
        div className = "App" >
        <
        header className = "App-header" >
        <
        img src = { logo }
        className = "App-logo"
        alt = "logo" / >
        <
        p >
        Edit < code > src / App.js < /code> and save to reload. <
        /p> <
        a className = "App-link"
        href = "https://reactjs.org"
        target = "_blank"
        rel = "noopener noreferrer" >
        Hello CodeCademy <
        /a> <
        /header> <
        /div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I tried to install another formatter and go to my settings to remove my "html" "twig" extension in emmet.

Comment: Which one of those is "strange" and what would you expect?

Comment: @A_A The second one is obviously stranger than the first one...

Comment: @A_A Because for some inexplicable reason, Prettier et al decide that, since the code being formatted is JSX, it's going to simply discard indentation on the HTML-in-JS, while simultaneously treating (from a formatting perspective) every `<` as an operator (but not `>`; that would be silly) instead of the `&lt;` that behaviorally it should see it as. The formatter (again, I think Prettier, in this case) sees the file extension is .JSX, and appears to just throw its hands up when it encounters the embedded HTML (which really is a "sub-language" in this instance, necessitating its own formatter)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. `CTRL + SHIFT + P`
2. Format Document (in pop-up bar)
3. Select `Format Document`
4. Select `Configure Default Formatter...`
5. Select `Prettier - Code formatter`

To enable `Format On Save`

1. `CTRL + SHIFT + P`
2. Preferences Open Settings (UI) (in pop-up bar)
3. Type `Format On Save`
4. Enable `Format On Save` if it is not checked

Done!

Comment: Hooray! Now it butchers the formatting _every time he saves_! That IS quite the time-saver!

Answer (score 0):

Download the Prettier extension for VSCode. Follow this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/automatically-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-when-working-with-react-c48674a12dc5).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, even thus I have installed the **[Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)** extension. It shows later that I have had another extension called **JS-CSS-HTML Formatter**. I uninstalled **JS-CSS-HTML Formatter** and kept **Prettier**, and all problem was solved.

This issue is mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/381) as well.